# Just execute an IF until the value is changed Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a web page to analyze the stock of some shoes, I did it as I would like but I would need to add one thing, and that is, for example, when suddenly there is a stock of a shoe size, it sends me a Discord webhook with the size that there is stock, but it keeps sending me webhooks all the time until it stops having stock, the thing is that I would like to do that when it fulfills the function of the if, it sends the webhook, but the next time I check If the stock is still in stock, do not send me any webhook until it is out of stock and then back in stock, I don't know if I have explained myself well.

I want it to fulfill the function once it only executes it once even though it continues to fulfill that function, only to fulfill it again when the stock status returns to out of stock and then to with stock

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from dhooks import Webhook, Embed
import requests
import pandas as pd
import logging
from json import loads
import time, datetime
import random
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth
import time 
import multiprocessing
import re



headers = {

}


def monitor2(url):

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

marca = soup.find("h3", {"class":"OEhtt9 ka2E9k uMhVZi uc9Eq5 pVrzNP _5Yd-hZ"}).text
nombre = soup.find("h1", {"class":"OEhtt9 ka2E9k uMhVZi z-oVg8 pVrzNP w5w9i_ _1PY7tW _9YcI4f"}).text
color = soup.find("span", {"class":"u-6V88 ka2E9k uMhVZi dgII7d z-oVg8 pVrzNP"}).text
precio = soup.find("span", {"class":"uqkIZw ka2E9k uMhVZi FxZV-M z-oVg8 pVrzNP"}).text
talla = soup.find("span", {"class":"u-6V88 ka2E9k uMhVZi FxZV-M z-oVg8 pVrzNP"}).text
imagen = soup.find("img", {"class": "_6uf91T z-oVg8 u-6V88 ka2E9k uMhVZi FxZV-M _2Pvyxl JT3_zV EKabf7 mo6ZnF _1RurXL mo6ZnF PZ5eVw"})['src']
api = 'https://api.silverpings.eu/zalando?skuid='

tallas = soup.find_all(re.compile("script"))[15]
tallas2 = re.findall(r'size":.....', str(tallas))
tallas3 = str(tallas2).replace('size":"',"").replace('"', "").replace(']', "").replace("'", "").replace(",", "").replace("[Te", "").replace("r", "").replace("tall", "").replace("¿Cuá", "").replace("}", "").split()
tallas3 = sorted(list(set(tallas3)))

skus = soup.find_all(re.compile("script"))[15]
skus2 = re.findall(r"sku.......................", str(skus))
skus3 = str(skus2).replace('sku":"',"").replace("'", "").replace("'","").replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("silh", "").replace("uri", "").replace(",", "").replace(" ", "")
skus4 = str(skus3).strip()
skus5 = re.findall(r".........-...\d......", str(skus4))

disponibilidad = soup.find_all(re.compile("script"))[15]
disponibilidad2 = re.findall(r'quantity":.............', str(disponibilidad))
disponibilidad3 = str(disponibilidad2).replace('quantity":"',"").replace('"', "").replace(']', "").replace("'", "").replace(",", "").replace("[", "").replace("r", "").replace("tall", "").replace("¿Cuá", "").replace("}", "").split()

print("[",datetime.datetime.now().hour,":",datetime.datetime.now().minute,":",datetime.datetime.now().second,":",datetime.datetime.now().microsecond,"]", " Comprobando disponibilidad de: ("+nombre+")")

numero = 0

while numero <= len(tallas3):

    

    if not "OUT_OF_STOCK" in disponibilidad3[numero]:
            
        hook = Webhook('')
        embed = Embed(
        color=15105570,
        timestamp='now'  # sets the timestamp to current time
        )

        embed.url = (url)
        embed.title = (nombre+" " + color)
        embed.add_field(name='Talla', value="["+tallas3[numero]+"]("+api+skus5[numero]+")")
        embed.add_field(name='Precio', value=precio)
        embed.add_field(name='Useful Links', value="[Checkout](https://www.zalando.es/checkout/confirm)", inline=False)
        
        embed.set_footer(text='Zalando by SilverPings', icon_url="https://assets.stickpng.com/thumbs/5a32a860cb9a85480a628f95.png")

        embed.set_thumbnail(imagen)

        hook.send(embed=embed)
        print("[",datetime.datetime.now().hour,":",datetime.datetime.now().minute,":",datetime.datetime.now().second,"]", " Stock encontrado: ("+nombre + " - " + tallas3[numero]+")")

        numero = numero+1

    else:
        numero = numero+1
        if numero == len(tallas3):
            break

def gymred():
 url = 'https://www.zalando.es/nike-sportswear-air-force-1-07-zapatillas-light-bonewhite-ni112o0h3- 
 a12.html'
 monitor2(url)           

while True:
 gymred()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean value that becomes True when you send the webhook, and then look for this value to be false in order to send the email. The code would be something like this:

```
if not "OUT_OF_STOCK" in disponibilidad3[numero] and not enviado:
    
    enviado = True    
    hook = Webhook('')
    embed = Embed(
    color=15105570,
    timestamp='now'  # sets the timestamp to current time
    )

    embed.url = (url)
    embed.title = (nombre+" " + color)
    embed.add_field(name='Talla', value="["+tallas3[numero]+"]("+api+skus5[numero]+")")
    embed.add_field(name='Precio', value=precio)
    embed.add_field(name='Useful Links', value="[Checkout](https://www.zalando.es/checkout/confirm)", inline=False)
    
    embed.set_footer(text='Zalando by SilverPings', icon_url="https://assets.stickpng.com/thumbs/5a32a860cb9a85480a628f95.png")

    embed.set_thumbnail(imagen)

    hook.send(embed=embed)
    print("[",datetime.datetime.now().hour,":",datetime.datetime.now().minute,":",datetime.datetime.now().second,"]", " Stock encontrado: ("+nombre + " - " + tallas3[numero]+")")

    numero = numero+1

else:
    numero = numero+1
    if numero == len(tallas3):
        break
```

Then you could update this boolean value if you want to send another webhook but I will leave that to you.

Comment: Thanks! But when i try with this code, is constantly sending a webhook with size 40 in stock, you are spanish? Do you have discord or something like that?